# Where do I ask a question about Windows tablets?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm in the market for a Windows 8 tablet and would like to know what my options are, but can't find a particular SE board to post a question on. From the array of (mainly speculative) blog posts out there, it looks like are only about 5 mainstream (i.e. available globally and actually released) tablets, so I was hoping to just get a list of them, or a link to such a list.

Where do I ask this?

Comment: Create an [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) for Windows Tablet based questions.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - Done: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38765/windows-tablets (also, your name is awesome!)

Comment: Proposing/creating a new site does not solve the real problem. 
Required reading: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) You'll need to substantially reformulate your question in order for it to be on-topic *anywhere* on the network.

Comment: "available globally and actually released" Windows 8 is not actually out yet, so none of them are "actually released."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of June 2012, **[Super User is considering tablets to be computers](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers?cb=1)**, which effectively means that you can now ask questions about tablets on Super User *if* the question would be equally on-topic if it weren't about a tablet. Right now this is only semi-official, as we're giving it a trial run for a couple months to see if it works out.

For your particular question ("which Windows tablet should I get?), it wouldn't be considered on-topic because we don't allow shopping questions or product recommendations. That being said, if you do eventually get a tablet device and have questions about it, you can ask them on Super User.

If you have an [Android](http://android.stackexchange.com) tablet or [iPad](http://apple.stackexchange.com), you may also want to consider looking at their respective sites.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think there's such a Stack Exchange site for this purpose.

Comment: ...and in general, Stack Exchange doesn't like shopping or *"what's better, X or Y"* questions.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - Whilst I agree that many questions around that topic are bad for Stack Exchange, in this case I'm not asking which is better. I simply want to know what my options are, so I can decide for myself. Unfortunately the Windows tablet market is in such an infant state that there aren't (to my knowledge) any decent places where such a list has been coallesced.

Comment: ...which sounds like a shopping question, and those haven't in general fared well on SE sites. I'm not active on Super User, but I think they deal with this a lot. Note: I'm not saying it's a *bad* question, just likely [perceived](http://superuser.com/faq) as off-topic.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The trick is where you draw the line. A question should only be deemed *bad* if it has a negative effect on the quality of the site. Saying that all shopping-related questions are bad is wrong, because there are a few corner-case questions that are good. Whether this is a good one is, I suppose, a topic for debate. However, unless someone can find an explicit reason why the question itself is bad for Stack Exchange, instead of a blanket "all shopping questions are bad" response, it shouldn't be considered bad.

Comment: Well, it's "bad" by virtue of violating elements of the site's FAQ. Now, if you want to change that FAQ...

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta It violates parts of SuperUser's FAQ, but I never said I wanted to post it on SuperUser. It doesn't violate any parts of Stack Exchanges global ruleset.

Comment: That's true, @Poly. You can't post on SE itself, though. Good luck with your proposal - I'd be interested in an answer to your question.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Hence why I asked here. And thank you :)